# Default font when using Sans-Serif in CSS

Tags: css, windows-7, windows-10

Our company has a designer, who used the following CSS for choosing a font-family:

```
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
```

Recently I noticed, that some UTF8-Icons I used with this font, looks different on my computer at work, then at my home pc.

After further investigation I found out, that neither of the defined font is available at my home (Win7) nor my work (Win10) PC. On each PC I used Chromium browser to render the Website.

1. Is there a definition, or a rule of thump, which Font-Family is chosen when fallback 'sans-serif' is used.
2. How can I find out, which Font-Family was chosen by my browser? Event the computed value in Chrome dev tools seems to be wrong:

[image]

Comment: Scroll right to the bottom of that `Computed` tab (to the aptly-named "Rendered Fonts" section) and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Default fallback font for sans-serif is defined on a per Browser basis and can be changed by the User in the browsers settings: https://i.imgur.com/fEjQCGE.png (example Firefox). So to get a 'rule of thumb' you could install a fresh copy of each browser and see what the setting is set to as default.

Comment: @George That worked. Arial was used in Win7 and Sergoni UI in Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the computed tab, Then open the accordion "font-family" , then you can see the font which is currently using the browser.Refer the image shown below.[image]

Comment: This only shows, what was calculated based on my styles, not which font was actually used. @George actually gave the right answer.